# How to use ERP web application lookup data in desktop Selenium webdriver application?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have an ERP web application in which we are using a lookup that shows matches (from database) by typing.

I am working on a desktop Selenium webdriver application to test ERP application. How can I automate lookup in ERP application, using Selenium webdriver?

Following is code:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <span class="col-sm-3">
            <label><spring:message code="label.notify" text="Notify"/></label>
            <div id="memberList">
            <c:forEach items = "${memberListMap}" var="member">
              ${member.value}<a id='${member.key}' onclick='deleteMember(this.id)'><img  align='absmiddle' style='height:10px;' src='<c:url value='/resources/images/delete.jpg' />' alt='Delete' title='Delete' /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </c:forEach>
            </div>
            <div id="add_member_link" ><a class="light_blue" onclick="JavaScript:document.getElementById('resourceName').style.display='';document.getElementById('add_member_link').style.display='none';document.getElementById('resourceAjaxLookupDiv').style.display='none';">
            <b><img align="absmiddle" style="margin-right:5px;color:#3C78B7;" src='<c:url value="/resources/images/add_icon.png" />'></img>
                <spring:message code="label.addusers" text="Add users"/></b></a></div>

                <input class="form-control" ng-model="position.resourceName" name="resourceName" id="resourceName" style="width:200px;margin-right:20px;display:none"
                    onkeyup="return getResourceList('<c:url value="/user/resourceList" />', 'resourceAjaxLookupDiv');" autocomplete="off" />    
                <input type="hidden" name="resourceId" id="resourceId" />       

                <div id="resourceAjaxLookupDiv" style="text-align:center;min-height:18px;max-height:100px;width:203px;overflow:auto;
                background-color:#ffffff;display:none;border:1px solid #7f9db9;position:absolute;z-index:1000;border-top:0;">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="member_array" id="member_array" />   
            </span>                                             
        </div>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML of the lookup field and the match list.

Comment: Thanks, When I enter a character in lookup box, it shows matches from database. There is no fixed match list.

Comment: @PeterWippermann sir, can you please show some example code for lookup in webdriver and java?

Comment: No sorry, all I could do is googling as well. What about the HTML code of your application? Are you able to share it or not?

Comment: @PeterWippermann sir, I have added code for lookup. Can you please view?

Comment: The code you posted is not your actual HTML but the code in your UI definition language (JSF Facelets? JSP?). Anyway, I'll make a best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Automating your lookup consists of two steps:

1. [Type](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) text in the lookup field
2. [Click](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click--) an entry in the matches list

Since both UI elements are given an ID, [finding](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) them should be easy:

`WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.id("element id"));`

As far as I can tell, your IDs are `resourceName` and `resourceAjaxLookupDiv`.

Since your lookup appears to be an asynchronous AJAX request (opposed to a page reload), you certainly want to define an explicit [WebDriverWait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to wait until the list has been loaded.